# Indecipherable Characters with UART on Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, uart

I am attempting to use the UART pins on the Raspberry Pi 2 to interface with the console port on a Cisco Access Point.

I've stripped an old RJ45 cable to connect the right TX, RX and GND pins from the console port to the UART ports on my Pi.

I have enabled UART through `raspi-config` and disabled the serial console.

I know from previous tutorials that the correct baud rate from this AP is 9600, and I'm opening a console using Minicom `sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 9600`

Unfortunately, I only receive indecipherable characters:

[image: Indecipherable characters in a console]

I know these symptoms usually relate to incorrect baud rate setting, so I've tried all of the following to no avail:

- 300
- 1200
- 2400
- 4800
- 9600
- 19200
- 38400
- 57600
- 115200
- 230400
- 460800
- 500000
  They all produce different sets of characters but none are readable.

On one occasion I did get some partially correct text but this never occurred again:

[image: partially readable text]

I've tried the following tasks:

- Adding `core_freq=250` to `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting.
- Adding `force_turbo=1` to `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting.
- Adding `init_uart_baud=9600` to `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting.
- Adding `init_uart_clock=48000000` to `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting.
- Using Raspi-OS instead of Ubuntu Core.
- Various combinations of parity, data bits and flow control.
- Using UART1 instead of UART0 on the same pins GPIO14 and 15 by adding into `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtparam=uart0=off
dtparam=uart1=on
dtoverlay=uart1,txd1_pin=14
dtoverlay=uart1,rxd1_pin=15
```

I also had to add `8250.nr_uarts=1` into `/boot/cmdline.txt`

None of these made any difference. I am out of ideas and looking for advice on further troubleshooting my UART pins in case they may be broken, or anything else that might make this work.

Comment: I could not find out from a quick online search, and you should make it explicit: What  is the logic level voltage of the console port on the Cisco device?  I suspect it is higher than 3.3V.  You may be risking damage to the Pi this way.  *If you do not know the voltage,* do not connect them again until you find out.

Comment: If the serial interface is on a 9 or 25-way 'D' type connector, then it is probably incompatible with your 3.3V Pi I/O; it could be up to +/- 15 volts, and may well damage the Pi. You need to level-shift the signals, or just use a USB-to-serial adaptor that has a similar 9-way connector.

Comment: @goldilocks can I measure the voltage using a multimeter? Couldn't find a guide for it which wires do I connect to?

Comment: Generally UART buses have the TX pin held high when idle.  I can't guarantee that is the case here, but you could try it.   Make sure you have the wires spread out or attached to a breadboard so you can test on pins, because if you send that TX pin straight to ground it could wreck the port, amongst other things.

Comment: @goldilocks both multimeter cables connect to the TX pin?

Comment: No, that's not how a volt/multimeter (or voltage) works.  Voltage is always a difference between two points, one of which is usually the ground from the same circuit.  So the voltage on the TX pin is relative to the GND.  If it is zero, the line is not being pulled high.   Otherwise, it should give the logic level of the port.  However, there is a complication in that the pin may also be "floating", which will give a false reading.  You should do your best to research this device for confirmation -- surely everything ever made by Cisco is documented online?

Comment: Also, you may wish to take this up on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/); include a photograph of the jack and some more details about the device (specific model etc).